# How to Save to an Array and display array in listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-edittext

I use this code to save the contents of a `EditText` (name) to an array, i'm wanting to then display this array in a list view on another activity. any idea? thanks

SingleItemView:

```
ArrayList<String> addArray = new  ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(SingleItemView.this, mygardenMain.class);
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();

public void onClick(View v) {
        String getInput = txt.getText().toString();

        if (addArray.contains(getInput)){
            Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,"Plant Already Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,"No Plant Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            addArray.add(getInput);
            Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,"Plant Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("addArray",addArray);

intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

mygardenMain code:

```
public class mygardenMain extends Activity {

private ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> addArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mygarden_list);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mygardenlist);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> addArray = bundle.getStringArrayList("addArray");


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mygardenMain.this,           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
    }
```

Comment: So your problem is to pass the ArrayList addArray to another activity in the onClick method?

Comment: yes, the idea is to create a favourites list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code to do this. to send String array from one Activity to next Activity.

```
 String[] stringArray = new String[10];
 Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyDrawing.class);
 Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
 bundle.putStringArray("stringArray",stringArray);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And Retrive Array in Next Activity from Intent like below:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 String[] stringArray = bundle.getStringArray("stringArray");
```

You can pass Array List Directly to Intent

```
 ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyDrawing.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putStringArrayList("arraylist",arraylist);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And Retrieve like below:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> arraylist = bundle.getStringArrayList("arraylist");
```

Comment: Hello, can this same method be used with: ArrayList<String> addArray = new  ArrayList<String>();

Comment: yes , Bundle has method to put Arraylist<String > object .

Comment: Ive tried this method, I get a notification saying applications with this function have been blocked? Also on manual navigation without intent to the retrieve class it says....Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: Bundle Accept ArrayList obejct , if you are try to pass List<String> arraylist , reference its does not work, for this you have to cast List object to ArrayList and When you retrive then hold ArrayList into List reference.

Comment: is there a way I can send or show you the code I have? thanks

Comment: I have updated my original question with current code

Comment: intent.putExtras(bundle); this Line is missing , Add  this line  before startActivity().

Comment: I still get the error:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:508)

Comment: Have you added  
intent.putExtras(bundle);  this line , And As par your code if you code goes to else condition then you put ArrayList<String> addArray , into Bundle , So is this else block executed or not .please debug your code or print Logs to check your code is ruining according your expections

Answer (score 0):

Use Parcelable to send and receive data between activities.

To send

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive,

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

finally set listview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BasicViews5Activity extends ListActivity {
 String[] presidents = {
 “Dwight D. Eisenhower”,
 “John F. Kennedy”,
 “Lyndon B. Johnson”,
 “Richard Nixon”,
 “Gerald Ford”,
 “Jimmy Carter”,
 “Ronald Reagan”,
 “George H. W. Bush”,
 “Bill Clinton”,
 “George W. Bush”,
 “Barack Obama”
 };

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //---no need to call this---
 //setContentView(R.layout.main);
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));
 }

 public void onListItemClick(
 ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
 Toast.makeText(this,
 “You have selected “ + presidents[position],
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

hope this helps
the String{} presidents is the array

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

from:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Build an Intent
An Intent is an object that provides runtime binding between separate components (such as two activities). The Intent represents an app’s "intent to do something." You can use intents for a wide variety of tasks, but in this lesson, your intent starts another activity.

In MainActivity.java, add the code shown below to sendMessage():

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is how you pass String in android to the next activity.
This could be adapted to add an array or values in an array potentially as and object or as string through a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

**try this.**

**first convert ArrayList to array and then pass to next activity**

String [] arrrayData = addArray.toArray(new String[addArray.size()]);

**get like this**

```
String[] array;
 Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyDrawing.class);
 Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
 bundle.putStringArray("array",array);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**100% working**

Answer (score 0):

please be specific with your question.Secondly ListView is outdated,my advise to you is to use Recycler view

```
 private RecyclerAdapter ra;
 private ArrayList<ModalClassName> yourarraylistname;


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerdown);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
   yourarraylistname =new ArrayList<ModalClassName>();
  //make sure yourarraylistname has some value
    ra = new DownloadAdapter(this,yourarraylistname);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(ra);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my ListView Example project on github. Here is the link

https://github.com/SanjayKushwah0601/ListView-Example

You can pass the ArrayList via intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", addArray);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And then you can fetch this ArrayList on another screen

```
// Now fetch the contents from intent
        addArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This works well, but when I manually go to the ListActivity I get an error. I also would like it to not automatically navigate to that view once added and to be able to add multiple entries.

Comment: @user4682589 I have updated the github project you can go through it. here is the link [link]https://github.com/SanjayKushwah0601/ListView-Example

Comment: Ive checked the code and although it allows me to pass the data I am needing it to save a number of inputs and output them when navigated to manually.

Comment: The button is located on another activity, is there a way?